# How to set the duty cycle to a desied value

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to study the performance of B-MAC/X-MAC while varying the duty cycle ratio using INET framework. I know for wireless sensor networks, duty cycle is the ratio of active period and the summation of sleelping period and active period.Can anyone please explain for XMAC, which parameter(s) actually defines the duty cycle ratio?

For example, if I want to set the duty cycle to 5%, which parameters need to be considered in omnetpp.ini file, and what should be those parameters' values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in XMac and BMac you can only set the slotDuration (which is the sleep period of the nodes). The active period can be variable in length, depending on what happens in the network, and what messages the node receives or transmits, etc. So the duty cycle is variable in length as well.

Comment: Yes, I know the slotDuration is the sleep period. But I wonder how active period is defined to make a fixeed duty cycle. In some papers, I found authors studied the X-MAC performance by changing the duty cycle, e.g. 1%, 5%, etc. Do you know how to do that? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the code of XMac and BMac, but as far as I know, there is no parameter for that. You might be able to configure BMac to get a constant duration active period, by setting the number of retries to 1. Then the duration of the active period could be calculated, and the duty cycle could be varied with the sleep period.